# LU decomposition of a matrix similar to tridiagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let A be a matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
>  *& *& 0& 0& *\\
>  *& *& *& 0& 0\\ 
>  0& *& *& *& 0\\ 
>  0& 0& *& *& *\\
>  *& 0& 0& *& *\ \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> that has an $LU $decomposition, i.e. $A=LU$. Which entries in $L$ and
>   $U$ may be zero and which may be non-zero$?

**My attempt:**
I know that if $B$ is tridiagonal and has $LU$ decomposition, then the left lower triangular matrix $L$ will be 
$$L=\begin{bmatrix} 
1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
*& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& *& 1& 0& 0\\
0& 0& *& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 0& *& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
and right upper triangular matrix will be $$U=\begin{bmatrix} 
*& *& 0& 0& 0\\
0& *& *& 0& 0\\
0& 0& *& *& 0\\
0& 0& 0& *& *\\
0& 0& 0& 0& *
\end{bmatrix}$$.

In general case $L$ is just a left lower triangular matrix with 1 on the main diagonal and $U$ is the right upper triangular matrix. However in this problem is there a special $LU$ decomposition for the matrix A like in the tridiagonal case?

Comment: The LU factors do indeed have a special structure. Can you try to perform the factorization symbolically on the given matrix? Perhaps it’s similar to the tridiagonal case with something happening in the last row and colum of the L and U factors, respectively.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel, can the elements on the main diagonal of $U$ be zero? If not, why?

Comment: They can be zero if the matrix is singular but generally they are not.